# UIView in UICollectiveViewCell can't hidden

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I got a UICollectionView that I have created programmatically. I would like to have a  collection view to behave in the following direction:

1. User touches cell
2. hidden uiview that cover image
3. User touches cell again
4. show uiview to cover the image

1.) Before user touch image in cell it look like this

http://upload.siamza.com/1811355

2.) After user touch image in cell it will look like this

http://upload.siamza.com/1811359

3.) If user touch image again it 'll look like 1.)

right now my select and deselect is look like this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(collectionView == genrescollectView){

    genresRecCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"genresRecCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.checkforselectView.hidden = FALSE;

    }
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(collectionView == genrescollectView){

     genresRecCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"genresRecCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.checkforselectView.hidden = TRUE;

    }
}
```

but it seen to be not working at

cell.checkforselectView.hidden = FALSE;

and

cell.checkforselectView.hidden = TRUE;

I have check in cellForItemAtIndexPath for work or not by adding
 cell.checkforselectView.hidden = FALSE;

and it work so I wonder anyone could help me with this problem and this is now in cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        genresRecCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"genresRecCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *imageGenres = [genresData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.genresImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageGenres];
        NSString *textToParse = imageGenres;
        NSArray *components = [textToParse componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *genresText = [components firstObject];
        cell.labelGenres.text = genresText;
        cell.genresImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        cell.genresImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        //---------> this is where I check whether it work or not(and it work).
        cell.checkforselectView.hidden = FALSE;

        return cell;

}
```

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

use

`[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

instead of dequeing a new cell

Comment: I've been combing the internet for 4 hours looking for a solution to a similar problem and this resolved my problem also, THANK YOU!